# how to send the image dynamically through mail from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

That my image is in bit formate in the database , how would i retrive from the database  & send that image through email body.

I have tried that using the attachment but , i dnt knw how to send that image in mail body.

Comment: You shouldm post your code and provide any error messages that occur. Without that information people can't/won't help you.

Comment: I have to disagree with you there. It's a simple and clear question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a HTML formatted message:

```
string img = Convert.ToBase64String(yourImgArray, 0, yourImgArray.Length);
string imgString = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + img + "' alt='Your Image Alt' width='80' height='15'>";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("noreply@youremail.com"),
    Subject = "your subject",
    Body = "your message body with image: " + imgString,
    IsBodyHtml = true
};
```